# Why does created histogram using ggplot2 always differ from examples in the tutorials?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tested a couple of tutorials about how to create histograms using ggplot2 like this [one](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-histogram-with-ggplot2/). I think that I understand the concept however I am not sure why my created histograms slightly differ from the ones in the tutorials. Here is one [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjhnj.png) which actually should look like the first histogram in the tutorial I mentioned above.

I am using RStudio with R v3.3.1 and ggplot2 v2.1.0.

Comment: ggplot2 v2 changed lots of defaults in subtle way. That would explain such minuscule differences.

Comment: Providing examples of you code and data. would be nice.

Comment: @Warner I always used exactly the same code as in the tutorials.

Comment: As @KonradRudolph mentioned there might be small differences in the defaults of ggplot2 v2. Looking at your picture one main difference between your graph and the one in the tutorial is that your minor grid lines are as thick as your major grid lines. I would look up `theme` elements within a ggplot graph and see how to adjust this. `panel.grid.minor` and `panel.grid.major` control the color and thickness of your grid lines.

Answer (score 0):

This a current [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1565) in `ggplot2`. A solution exists, but with major changes coming shortly, has not been implemented yet. If necessary, you can use

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("Katiedaisey/ggplot2")
```

to install the fixed version directly from my github fork.